# Piping unfiltered text to an awk system command's stdin

Tags: awk, gawk

I have an gawk script that has accumulated a bunch of HTML in a variable, and now should pipe it to lynx via a system command.

(feel free to tell me AWK is a bad solution... `while read LINE;` was wildly bad (slow), so this is take 2)

I tried this in awk:

```
    cmd = sprintf( "bash -c \'lynx -dump -force_html -stdin <<< \"%s\"\'", html )
    system ( cmd )
```

Bad idea, although simple test cases work, with raw HTML, special character issues and string termination issues abound, and escapes-within-escapes-within-escapes is just getting mindbogglingly complex.

lynx handles well whatever I throw at it on stdin, I just can't get it to stdin from awk without piping it through the the command line, which seems like an unwieldy solution.

---

Edit (adding detail about my end goal) in case awk isn't a good approach:

What I want is to parse HTML out of a large text file with delimiters between blocks of html. I need to pass each block of HTML to lynx to be formatted and dump that into a new, big text file.

---

Example input (a dump from another system):

```
**********URL: http://some/url
<html>
<head><title>Any 'ol HTML document</title</head>
<body>
<p>With pretty much any character you can imagine at some point</p>
<p>I'm using lynx to strip off the HTML and give me a nice format</p>
</body>
</html>
**********URL: http://another/url
<html><head><title>My input file provides a few 100,000 such html documents</title></head>
<body/></html>
```

Each HTML document should be feed through `lynx -dump`. Lynx can read in the HTML from file (e.g. named pipe, or file is an option), or stdin (with the -stdin option).

My output is then:

```
**********URL: http://some/url
  Any 'ol HTML document

  With pretty much any character you can imagine at some point
  I'm using lynx to strip off the HTML and give me a nice format
**********URL: http://another/url
  My input file provides a few 100,000 such html documents
```

Comment: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem

Comment: Aye, if there's no solution in awk, that's a fine answer and I'll move on. But awk is big and I'm a relative beginner with it, so it's hard for me to know that for sure without asking. Do you know awk well enough to say that?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what `a bunch of HTML` is as well as what you're expecting `lynx` to do to it with some sample inputs/outputs?  Also - just found out about [`|&` for gawk](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Two_002dway-I_002fO.html#Two_002dway-I_002fO) coprocesses today ([seen here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24066356/1259917)) which seems like something you could use.

Comment: Raw HTML source code from random sites across the web. That link to awk coprocesses sure looks like it hits the nail on the head, going to try it first thing in the morning. I added more detail about my end goal in the question.

Comment: @DavidParks if you cannot give a sample input, even a fake one, I feel this question is going nowhere.

Comment: Can't you just do `awk 'program' file.txt | lynx` instead? And print to stdout from within 'program'.

Comment: @Steven Penny I was on my mobile phone when I responded to comments last night, just got back to the computer now and added the example input/output.

Comment: @n0741337 Thanks for your link, I'm playing with gawk coprocesses with great hope now (hadn't come across them before)

Comment: @George Kirilov There are probably 100,000 individual HTML documents in my text file, each lynx process can only handle one as far as I'm aware, I can't pipe it multiple pages (if that assumption is wrong it'd be a big oversight).

Comment: @n0741337 Your a genius, I was fixated on using system(), I didn't even know gawk co-processes existed (the gawk docs have it, but it's not in the major awk tutorials), just did a simple test and it works brilliantly, a pipe directly in AWK. Can you post that as an answer so I can credit you for it? Just the link to that other question was perfect (it had further links that provided details), I'll edit your answer with a little example I did for future reference.

Comment: @DavidParks - Cool.  I'm glad that it's working for you - edit away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [`|&` in gawk.](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Two_002dway-I_002fO.html#Two_002dway-I_002fO), which I found out about from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24066356/1259917).  That would let you send the output from gawk to the stdin of another command as a coprocess.

Comment: I achieved my goal of parsing all embedded HTML documents with lynx in an elegant 10 line gawk script (with half dedicated just to opening/closing the coprocess), this hint was hugely helpful!

Answer (score 0):

To add to n0741337's answer, here's an example using gawk coprocesses I did after reading his answer, it takes "aline" from stdin, and pipes it to a cat coprocess, and captures the output from the cat coprocess and prints it:

```
printf "aline" | awk '
  BEGIN{cmd="cat"} 
  {
    print $0 |& cmd; 
    close(cmd, "to"); 
    while ((cmd |& getline line) > 0) { 
      print "got", line 
    }; 
    close (cmd);
  }'

result: got aline
```

The gawk manual has a more extensive discussion of this feature: http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Two_002dway-I_002fO.html#Two_002dway-I_002fO